# How to calculate how many times a number goes into another number

Tags: c++

This is the program with the initial 'number' stated in the question taken as 'n' and the 'other number' taken as 10.

```
void divideme()
    static int count=0; //initalised a variable which I'll be returning the value of.
    int n;
    cin>>n;//taken input of variable which I want to divide by another number (say 10 in this case)
    int &rem=n;//created a reference variable which stores the value of n.

            while (rem>=10) {
                rem=rem%10; //this is to be corrected as rem = rem - 10;
                count++;
            }



    return count;
```

Comment: I dont understand the logic of your code. Any number modulo 10 is between 0 and 9 and taking the modulo again does not change that result. You should take pen and paper and think of a different way. Hint: If you want to count division use division and not the remainder.

Comment: "count how many times it divides by 10" => "divide by 10 until it does not divide, while counting"

Comment: btw it is not really clear what you want to do. If you have a double value you can divide it by 10 as many times as you like. For a integer, you are basically counting the trailing zeros, is this what you want to do?

Comment: I think its pretty straightforward. The rem = rem%10 had to be replaced by rem = rem-10 so that in the next loop, the number which is to be divided is reduced by the same factor that I want the next loop to run by and the count is increased accordingly.

Comment: Please edit your question to make it more clear what you were trying to do. The fact that this was just integer division is really confusing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `%` operator give you the modulus, which is the remainder after division.

If you just want to count the number of times that 10 goes into a number `rem`, then replace

```
rem=rem%10;
```

with

```
rem = rem - 10;
```

in your loop.

(Also, you don't need `if (rem>=10)` in your code. The while loop takes care of this.)

Comment: as I understand the text, he is looking for x such that 10^x <= n and not for x = n/10

Comment: @tobi303 I think x = n/10 is what he's looking for.

Comment: you might be correct, but this is not "how many times the number can be divided by 10". And if you are right, I would simply use integer division as in `x = n/10` instead of a loop

Comment: @tobi303 "how many times the number can be divided by 10" is always 1, so I was guessing that the OP meant how many times 10 goes into a number. Yes, this is just integer division. I assume the OP is doing this for an assignment.

Answer (score 6):

Your code is overkill. Just do the division one time. The result is the number of times 10 goes into the number. No loop is needed at all. The `%` operator gives you the modulus (remainder) of a division, which is not what you need in this situation.

```
int divideme()
{
    int n;
    cin>>n; //get input which I want to divide by another number (say 10 in this case)
    return (n / 10);//return how many times it divides by 10
}
```

For example:

```
9 / 10 = 0
9 % 10 = 9
```

10 goes into 9 0 times, with a remainder of 9.

```
12345 / 10 = 1234
12345 % 10 = 5
```

10 goes into 12345 1234 times, with a remainder of 5.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>


int times_divided_by_10(int x)
{
  return int(std::log10(double(x)));
}


int main()
{
  std::cout << times_divided_by_10(101) << std::endl;
}
```

expected output:

```
2
```

another way:

```
#include <iostream>

int times_divided_by_10(int x)
{
    int count = 0;
    while (x >= 10) {
        ++count;
        x /= 10;
    }
    return count;
}


int main()
{
    std::cout << times_divided_by_10(101) << std::endl;
}
```